# What does "$this.block();" do in jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: jquery

In my JavaScript file, I have jQuery code with the following function:

```
$('h3', '.js-accordion').click(function(e) {
    ..........
    ..........
    $this = $(this);
    $this.block();
    ..........
    ..........
}
```

I am trying to understand what the `block()` function does in `$this.block();`. Is it a jQuery function or a general JavaScript function? I found at https://forum.jquery.com/topic/blockui-block-function-does-not-seem-to-respect-local-options-overrides someone asking about the `blockUI: block()` function, but I am trying to find the official documentation to see what this function does, its syntax, and examples. Thank you.

EDIT: I am upgrading jQuery and I see this pop-up when I reload the page:

[image]

I am suspecting the `block()` is from the blockUI plugin.

Comment: Try `console.log($('h3', '.js-accordion').block);`

Comment: `block` is part of a plugin - http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element

Comment: There's no way to know what it does without knowing what plugins and libraries you have included. It might be the one Paul links to, or something else. It's not a standard jQuery method.

Comment: `I am trying to find the official documentation` - ... Google: jquery block UI -- Top Result: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/ -- For everything else is MasterCard

Comment: @JJJ It helps to know that it is not a standard jQuery nor JavaScript method. That was the hint I was looking for. I am using a plugin called "`blockUI: block() Version 2.09 (09/16/2008)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PaulFitzgerald and @JJJ and @Fran suggested in the comments, the `block()` function I mentioned in my question is from this plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element.